# Node hierarchy inheritance, creation and the return type confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance, nodes

Goodday to everyone.

Lets say I have such node hierarchy.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node (Node* parent, const std::string &name) :
             parent(0), name(name)
    {
        if (parent)
            parent->AddChild(this);
    }
    virtual ~Node ()  { ......... }

    virtual Node* CreateChild (const std::string& name);   // 
    virtual Node* GetChild (const std::string& name) // <--- 

    Node* parent;
    std::string name;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Node*> children;
};

class SceneNode : public Node
{
public:
    SceneNode (Node *parent, const std::string &name) :
            Node(parent, name), id(1)   { }
    virtual ~SceneNode ()  {  }
    // all scenenode stuff like seting rotatin, position and so on
    ..................................

    virtual void Render () = 0;
    virtual void ShowBoundingBox () = 0;

    int id;
};

class SceneSphereNode : public SceneNode
{
public:
    SceneSphereNode (Node *parent, const std::string &name) :
                             SceneNode (parent, name)   {  }
    virtual ~SceneSphereNode ()  { }

    void GetModel ()
    {
        std::cout << "getting model \n";
    }

    void ShowBoundingBox ()  { }
    void Render ()
    {
        std::cout << "Doing sphere render \n";
    }
};

class SceneManager
{
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Node*> staticNodes;

    SceneManager () {}
    virtual ~SceneManager ()
    {
     // delete static nodesnodes   
    }
    ..........................................
    SceneNode* GetNode (const std::string &name)
    {
        // whatever whenever ............ some code
        Node *someNode = // it calls Node::GetChild     
        return dynamic_cast<SceneNode*>(someNode);      
    }

};
```

*PS: The code may not be working, its just to show the idea of the problem.*

The main problem is that I want to have a "general" `Node` class which could be used in widgets, xml and so on. I dont want to put the hole messy stuff from SceneNode to Node (which actualy would solve the problem by creating Node not sceneNode). But then the problem arise.

Lets say SceneManager allready has some object and I want to get one:

```
SceneManager manager;
SceneNode* node1 = new SphereNode ("Node1", manager.GetRootNode());
manager.GetNode("Node1");  // <-- there ??? :(
```

There it returns `Node*` and I have to `dynamic_cast` it to `SceneNode*`. But since its a sceneManager and a lot stuff with rendering is going on there (that dynamic_cast) stuff may be very performance hungry and somehow I feel in my guts that something isn't very smart there.

Can you sugest what should I fix, maybe take some different approach.

Sorry for my low english skills and thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would not try to roll to many unrelated concepts into one class, ie XML nodes is a very different thing than scene nodes, and there's very little gained from deriving them from the same base. dynamic_cast can be very costly, but there's a few techniques which can be used:

- If the target of the cast always is exactly the same type as the node ( ie, you only store leafs ), then it's possible to just check with `typeid()` instead.
- If a failed `dynamic_cast` is considered an error condition, then you can stick with `dynamic_cast` for debug & internal release builds, but use `static_cast` for release candidates. Such a cast would more or less just be a free template function which wraps the cast and contains a `#ifdef` to either `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider the `visitor` pattern which eliminates the need for dynamic_cast.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern